# How to I separate a Web+App into separate web and app projects

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a web+app project on Google analytics and it has a lot of data on it I don't want to lose. But... App+Web is not good and makes it ridiculously difficult to see important pieces of data.

How can I separate them into either two separate properties or views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot separate data that has already been collected into different properties (and views do not even exist in Apps+Web).

If you want to look at App data and Web data separately, you'd have you use filters/segmentation.

Your best chance is to wait until BigQuery integration becomes available and then export the data and write your own aggregations, although that is probably not easier than working with Apps+Web in the first place.

Also this is still a beta, so with enough user feedback they might improve the UI to make data (including already collected data) more easily accessible. But as for short term fixes, there are none.

Answer (score 1):

You can see `Technology` report: Cross-platform, Web or App.

You can also use `Analysis --> Exploration` report and create custom reports.